# Accumulation points/interior points/closedness

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let

$$S_1 :=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} | Re(z) \geq 0 \land Re(z)+Im(z) < 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$$
$$S_2 :=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} | Re(z) > 0 \land Re(z)+Im(z) < 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$$

I need to determine the set of interior points, accumulation points and decide whether it's open/closed or neither.

**Interior Points:**

It is a little bit difficult, would the set of interior points for $S_1$ be all z, for which $Re(z)>0$ $\land$ $Re(z)+Im(z)<0$
and $S_2$ has only interior points? but how to prove that?

and how could I argue about the closedness and accumulation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\text{Re}(z)=\dfrac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$, it is easy to see that $f$ is continuous, similarly, $g(z)=\text{Im}(z)$, $g$ is continuous.

Now $S_{2}=f^{-1}(0,\infty)\cap (f+g)^{-1}(-\infty,1)$ which is open.

For the matter of accumulation points, suppose that $\text{Re}(z_{0})+\text{Im}(z_{0})=1$, consider then $z_{n}=z_{0}+i(\text{Im}(z_{0})-1/n)$, then $z_{n}\in S_{1}$ and $z_{n}\in S_{2}$ too.

Comment: thank you, but to be honest I do not really understand your approach. It would be great if you could provide further detail why S2 can be written like that, and what does it say about the openness of S1? and $z_n$ are all the possible accumulation points? I do not understand why $z_n$ can be written like that

Comment: Do you know that pre-images of open sets of continuous functions are open? Note that $S_{2}$ is a form of intersection of two sets. The $z_{n}$ is the limiting sequence which lies in the set, and so $\text{Re}+\text{Im}=1$ are accumulation points.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understood correctly S2 is a  intersection of two open sets and therefor also open, so all the points of S2 are interior points? But what about the openness of S1? I still do not understand the part about the accumulation points,  because a $z_0$ for which $Re(z_0)+Im(z_0)=1$   wouldn’t even be in neither S1 or S2?

Comment: $S_{1}$ is not open, as you draw a ball around the origin, the points at the negative $x$-axis wouldn't lie inside $S_{1}$. Accumulation points need no to be in the set.

Comment: Thank you, are the interior points of S1 the same as for S2? And how can  I show that the $z_0$ is the only accumulation point?

Comment: The interior points are the same. Actually the accumulation points are $\text{Re}(z)\geq 0$ and $\text{Re}(z)+\text{Im}(z)\leq 1$.